# Check text file for data, if there is any write to webbrowser with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a c program for a temperature sensor which create a file and write the temperature to the file and whether this is inside or outside some choosen values.
The data from file is supposed to be displayed on a webbrowser and updated every 5 min.

I was wondering if anyone could help me how to make a javascript, that checks the file and write the data to the webbrowser and "refresh" this data every 5 min according to the data in the text file.
Pretty "green" in javascript programming so hope someone could help me.

Comment: if the file is available via a http url, use ajax. if it's available on a local drive/path, use <input type=file> to grab the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
function refreshDivFromFile(){
    $("#div").load("file.txt");
}

window.setInterval(refreshDivFromFile, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

you need the div in your html:

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: thank! this updates the file every 5 min, but how to make the function write the data out on the webbrowser?

Comment: @Jacob This code on the client updates the browser every 5 minutes from the text file. It's on the server side that you need update the text file so the browser refreshes with the latest value.

Comment: @Jacob It sounds like you're already updating the text file from the server side, this code will update the browser with the data in the file.

Comment: hmm the file updates every 2 min when it measure temperature, so if this updates the browser i should be fine. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

javascript generally is a client side scripting language. This means outside of your browser it has no power.

So a purely html / javascript solution would not be able to talk to a text file on a machine.

What you want to look at is something such as php. Or any other server side processing language.

For your needs :
http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp would be a good place to start. There is a file read write example in there.